# background / jobs table in multi-term

Tags: multi-term

Is it possible to use the jobs table (`C-z` `bg` `jobs` `fg`) in `multi-term` (or another emacs terminal emulator)?

At present when I press `C-z` all of emacs is backgrounded to the system jobs table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send `C-z` directly to the shell, open your shell: `M-x shell` or `M-x term`, I did not try with `mutli-term`. Then, once inside the shell, execute:

`M-x local-set-key RET C-z self-insert-command`

After that, `C-z` should send to the background, the task actually running inside the command line, and not the whole Emacs.

If you want this configuration to be persistent. Then you should update your `init.el` file and add those lines:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-z") 'self-insert-command)))
```